# HttpURLConnection takes logged user instead of using provided Credentials for connecting a web service

Tags: java, c#, web-services, authentication

I created a Java Application to Connect the ASP.Net Asmx Web Service hosted in IIS 7 (Windows Server 2008 R2). The hosted site is configured to Authentication Type of Windows Authentication and provider as negotiate and ntlm

In Java Code I am using Authenticator Class to set username and password. This Code connects to the web service event if i give the password wrong. I checked the IIS logs, it actually uses the current logged on user to connect web service.

I tried debugging the Java Code after calling the `getPasswordAuthentication()` function java code validates the username and password using krb5 authentication method. At this point this throws an exception

> "Unable to locate Kerberos realm"

But this exception is handled at the java api and i am getting the response from the web service

Our requirement is to connect the web service with the provided credentials, if the provided credentials is wrong. it should return Unauthorized Access Code.

Below is my java Code.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class ConnectToUrlUsingBasicAuthentication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            String webPage = "http://servername/webservice/ABC.asmx/GetStudentReport";
            String name = "domain.lab\\sachin";
            String password = "Password123";

            //NtlmHandler handler = new NtlmHandler();

            Authenticator.setDefault(new NtlmAuthenticator(name, password));

            String authString = name + ":" + password;
            System.out.println("auth string: " + authString);
            byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
            String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);
            System.out.println("Base64 encoded auth string: " + authStringEnc);

            URL url = new URL(webPage);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            //conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " +authStringEnc );
            conn.connect();

            System.out.println("Response Code: " + conn.getResponseCode() );

            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
            InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

            int numCharsRead;
            char[] charArray = new char[1024];
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            while ((numCharsRead = isr.read(charArray)) > 0) {
                sb.append(charArray, 0, numCharsRead);
            }
            String result = sb.toString();

            System.out.println("*** BEGIN ***");
            System.out.println(result);
            System.out.println("*** END ***");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Below is the NtlmAuthenticator Class

```
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;

public class NtlmAuthenticator extends Authenticator {

      private final String username;
      private final char[] password;

      public NtlmAuthenticator(final String username, final String password) {
        super();
        this.username = new String(username);
        this.password = password.toCharArray(); 
      }

      @Override
      public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
          System.out.println("Scheme:" + getRequestingScheme() );
          System.out.println("Host:" + getRequestingHost() );
         PasswordAuthentication pa = new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
         System.out.println("UserName:" + pa.getUserName() );
         System.out.println("Password:" + pa.getPassword().toString() );
        return pa;

}
}
```

Please provide suggestion thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your client on windows then this behavior is as specified. The authentication process will first attempt to use the logged in user's credentials.

This is specified under the NTLM section in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-auth.html: 'On Microsoft Windows platforms, NTLM authentication attempts to acquire the user credentials from the system without prompting the user's authenticator object'.